# How to check if my device (iOS) have internet connection via bash

Tags: ios, ping

In linux using this line of code is easy:

```
if ping -c 4 google.com ; then echo OK ; else echo KO ; fi
```

But in iOS, `ping` command is not available. Any workaround? Or I can access a system plist file in iOS to get the connectivity status?